# iron-ajax - trying to send session cookie in the header of GET request

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to get my session cookie to be sent with my GET request using `iron-ajax`. Right now, there are no cookies in the request at all. Any suggestions?

```
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="{{apiHost}}/users/me"
  withCredentials="true"
  handle-as="json"
  versbose="true"
  requestHeaders='{"Cookie":"curves"}'
></iron-ajax>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `with-credentials` rather than `withCredentials`, and `headers` instead of `requestHeaders`. Looks like `requestHeaders` is a read-only property, `headers` is the settable property.

Also, XHRs can't set the `Cookie` header directly, it's set by the user agent: https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method